# Which is the head in "a number of boys"?

Tags: determiners, quantificational-nouns

> [A number of boys] were absent.
>   (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p56)

This book says that *number* is the head of the subject NP, but Angela Downing calls it a "determinative" (that is, a "complex quantifier", English Grammar p.433). When I read the sentence, Downing's term seems more natural. Then what's the possible reason Cambridge Grammar sees *number* as the head of the NP?

Comment: http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/detv_sli.pdf

Comment: Can someone explain why they think this is a "What's your favorite _____?" question?  There are four POB close votes, but as far as I can tell, this question asks about a fact ("Why does CGEL call *number* the head of *a number of boys*?").  If someone gives their opinion, they've probably given the wrong answer.

Comment: OP doesn't ask which we analysis consider correct, Downing or CGEL (which would indeed be a matter of opinion); she asks for the reasoning behind CGEL's analysis. Reopen.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding, but "what is the possible reason" (or, more simply, "why is it") certainly sounds opinion-based, hence my vote. Without the input of the CGEL's writers, it can't really be answered. (Apologies if I've been so blind as to overlook their presense on ELL.) There's [some old discussion on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105580/228098) about the subject. I'm happy to be wrong or to have misunderstood; more good questions are a good thing for the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context I think it's impossible to say that *number* is the head of the Subject noun phrase *a number of boys*.

I don't have CGEL, but in Huddleston's precis ([*A Short Overview of English Syntax*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html)) he

- distinguishes a *determinative* (a class of word or phrase) from a
  *Determiner* (a syntactic function) (3), and
- defines the Head of a noun phrase as a noun (7.1.b)

It would be consistent with these to say that *number* is the Head of the noun phrase *a number of* which acts as the Determiner of the Subject noun phrase *a number of boys*, thus:

> [<sub><sub>**SUBJECT NOUN PHRASE**</sub></sub> [<sub><sup><sub>**DETERMINER NOUN PHRASE**</sub></sup></sub> <sup><sup>Determiner</sup></sup> **a** <sup><sup>Head</sup></sup>  **number** <sup><sup>??</sup></sup> **of**] <sub><sup><sub>**HEAD**</sub></sup></sub> **boys**]

**REVISED September 2015:**
<s>But it may be just a slip, or an improper revision of a passage which was originally something beginning "The number of boys", or any number of things.</s>

I now have *CGEL* and find that it treats constructions of this sort at section 3.3 (pp. 349-50) under the heading **Non-count quantificational nouns**. In these expressions, where the "quantificational noun" (*number* in your example) is complemented by a preposition phrase *of* + "what we shall call the **oblique**" (*boys* in your example)

> ... the number of the whole NP depends on the oblique; we will say that [*number*] is **number-transparent** in that it allows the number of the oblique to percolate up to determine the number of the whole NP. [...] [I]t has been bleached of its original meaning and is a non-count noun [...] The *of* complement can be omitted in ellipsis, but it remains understood and continues to determine the number of the NP [...]

On pp. 351-2, under the heading "Syntactic structure of NPs like *a number of protesters*", *CGEL* contrasts the analysis I have given above with one which  understands the quantificational noun as head of the NP:

> [<sub><sub>NP</sub></sub> [<sub>Det</sub> **a**] [<sub>Head:Nom</sub> [<sup><sup>Head:N</sup></sup> **number**] [<sup><sup>Comp:PP</sup></sup> [<sup>Head:Prep</sup> **of**] [<sup>Comp:NP</sup> **boys**]]]]

*CGEL* gives fairly compelling syntactic reasons for preferring this analysis to mine.

- *of* forms a constituent with the oblique, not with *(a) number*

  > *a number __ prefer the old system*
  >   *a number of whom complain*
- *number* takes prehead dependents

  > *any number of boys*
  >   *a large number of boys*

I think there is something more to be said, but frankly I don't know what that something is. For the time being I think we have to take *number* as a head to which the construction imputes plurality.

Comment: @Listenever See my revision.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine for the same reason that

> a piece

is the head of

> a piece of paper

and

> a glass

is the head of

> a glass of water

Though I agree with your assessment of Angela Downing.

Answer (score 1):

The head of the noun phrase is "boys", with "A number of" being a quantifier premodifying the head.

Answer (score 1):

"A number of boys was/were injured"

I think you can see it grammatically, then it is "was injured", with number as head or main element of the noun group. As it seems this alternative is rare.

Mostly it is "were injured", seeing "a number of" logically as "a lot of". BNC  has mostly "a number of + noun pl + vb pl".

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+number+of+people+were%2C+a+number+of+people+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20number%20of%20people%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20number%20of%20people%20was%3B%2Cc0)

testden.com - Subject -Verb Agreement has an interesting remark:

A number of + noun plural + vb pl

The number of + noun pl + vb sg

https://www.testden.com/toeic/grammar-subject-verb-agreement.htm