# “Three eggs is plenty” Vs. “a number of boys were absent”?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I found these two sentences and I want an explanation for them to illustrate why they go like:

> - A number of boys **were** absent.

Although the subject is singular, but the sentence is considered as plural?

> - three eggs **is** plenty

And in this example, the writer used **is** instead of **are**.

Comment: "three eggs" is collective there. Replace it with "It": "It is plenty." Some collective nouns are considered plural; others could be considered both singular and plural. "A number of (noun)" is almost always treated as a plural (exception may be "a number of **times** is too many times", but this is because it is a collective "It" as the subject). Other ones that can be both are "jury", "group", "class", "crew", "audience", "committee", "staff (of people)", "team", "public", etc. Most collectives can be both, but "police" is always plural; however, "the law" can be both.

Comment: Incidentally, the "a number of boys were" passage is discussed at length in  [this related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/which-is-the-head-in-a-number-of-boys?noredirect=1&lq=1). Also related: the [_50 miles is_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13950/why-do-you-say-fifty-miles-is) question.

Comment: Does “a dozen schools” act like “a number of boys”?  @J.R.

Comment: @BavyanY - It depends on how it's used, which is explained quite well in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/145692).

Comment: @JR This question, namely "'Three eggs is plenty' vs. 'a number of boys were absent,'" is not an exact duplicate of "What is the head in 'a number of boys.'" The cited question is at an entirely different level of sophistication, and the highest ranked answer is appropriate to that sophistication. It may well be useless to the person initiating this thread. We have valued procedure over teaching. I have an entirely different view of the citation in your most recent comment. I would have had no objection had that been the initial citation. So I think we are on the right track now

Comment: @JeffM - That's why, the moment I closed the question, I also left a comment which read: I realize the "number of boys" question was only half of your question, but the other question ("three eggs is") has also been answered in questions like [_100 apples is_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145690/100-apples-are-is-considered-as-a-large-number-of-apples) and [_50 miles is_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13950/why-do-you-say-fifty-miles-is). That said, thanks to your feedback, I will change that duplication close message – and that comment – so as to flip the pointers.